# MKMapView Annotation Image Shifting from location

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mapkit

I have an MKMapview with a custom annotation image, when i click on the annotation i change the image for a bigger sized one and this causes the point to shift.

Is there a way to make sure the image gets aligned on the latitude and longitude again ?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    MKPointAnnotation * pin = view.annotation;

    if ([pin isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSMutableString * imageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[((SpotView *)self.baseView) generatePin:self.category]];

    [imageName appendString:@"-selected"];

    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

The results :

[image: Before Selection]
[image: After Selection]

Comment: Have you tried removing the annotation and adding it again? This should case the annotation view to reload (but I'm not sure if the animation will look nice).

Comment: This will indeed fiddle with the animation and im trying to avoid that

Comment: Why dont you try to set the offset of the image after you clicked on it.

Comment: Im getting strange behaviour when offseting the image, the image is set to the right location but as soon as i scroll it will get put back at the original (wrong) location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue using the following property in the `didSelectAnnotationView` method

```
customPinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(xOffset,yOffset);
```

and setting it back to zero in the `didDeselectAnnotationView` method

```
customPinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```